# How does Loader class assemble to $this in CodeIgniter 3 and How to upgrade Loader extensions to CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I am trying to understand CodeIngniter 3/4 from source code level. I found Loader class for $this->load->view/library etc. Since this "load" can be used by $this, it must be loaded somewhere and mix with $this. But I can't find where the Loader class be loaded. Would anyone familia CodeIgniter 3 introduce me how Loader be assemble to $this?

And

CodeIngniter 4 remove Loader class. I believe autoload must the one who replace the class. but I have some CI3 code extends from CI_Loader. How can I upgrade this classes to CI4? Example as below. How to rewrite My_Loader in CI 4.x

```
    <?php
    class My_Loader extends CI_Loader{}
```

Thanks.

Comment: CI 3.x system/core/Loader.php: check line ~190 public function library(...), there is where the magic comes from

Comment: Thanks buddy. Would you please get me further info since I am looking for: Where CI 3.x had loaded the Loader.php into memory?

Answer (score 0):

```php
// system/core/Controller.php
$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
```

It is the place how $this->load->view/library etc. happen.

CI 4.x doesn't use Loader anymore. use service as well